# Error in BGL documentation?

Tags: boost, documentation, boost-graph

In the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/graph/doc/isomorphism.html) of the algorithm `isomorphism` of the Boost Graph Library, it is stated that the named parameter `vertex_invariant1` and `vertex_invariant2` take a binary function as argument. However, the default value for these parameters is `degree_vertex_invariant`, which is a unary function object, according to the [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/boost/graph/isomorphism.hpp).

Am I missing something, or the documentation is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function_requires< AdaptableUnaryFunctionConcept<Invariant1, size_type, vertex1_t> >();
```

and

```
invariant1(kp1) == invariant2(u)
```

So yeah, I think the documentation is wrong. You should submit this to the mailing list IMO.

Comment: And btw, their invariant stuff is kinda useless. If my vertices are 2D points, how could I find a function that maps a 2D point to an integer in an unique way ? A comparison function between VertexType1 and VertexType2 would be more useful. Or maybe I didn't get something.